# Can I alter a market buy order?

Tags: steam

If I list a community market buy order I can select a quantity and price on the item in question. If I later decide to change the order I have to remove it and do it again. This has the negative effect of putting me to the back of the queue.

From [steam support](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214#buyordersnewlistings) (emphasis mine):

> ## How do buy orders choose which listing to buy?
>
> When you place a buy order, the market first looks for all the cheapest items that can fulfill your order. **Then the oldest listing (i.e. the seller who has waited the longest) is selected** and purchased. If the items are listed in multiple currencies, the amounts are first converted into your currency before being selected (i.e. a 0.03 RUB listing has no priority over a 0.03 USD listing)

I just realised I misread the quote above as that is for sellers not buyers. However, I belive the behaviour is the same.

Is there any way I can change a buy order without removing it?

Answer (score 2):

I do believe it is impossible to amend a buy or sell order. You can only retract your buy or sell order, and put the order back in at a different price.

Answer (score 0):

Buy orders cannot be edited: they can only be cancelled so that you can set new buy orders afterwards.

That being said, if you have several **unrestricted** accounts **with money as Steam Wallet**, you could:

- keep the original buy orders on your main account,
- set new buy orders on one of the other accounts.

This way, you would not lose your original buy orders, and could cancel them after the new buy orders are fulfilled.